# Static inheritance of array

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

It is kind of hard for me to explain what I am trying to do so I will just provide an example

```
class A {
    static $data = ['a'];

    static function getData() { return static::$data; }
}

class B extends A {
    static $data = ['b'];
}

class C extends B {
    static $data = ['c'];
}

class D extends B {
    static $data = ['d'];
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$c = new C;
$d = new D;

$a::getData(); // Output: Array('a'), Expected: Array('a');
$b::getData(); // Output: Array('b'), Expected: Array('a', 'b');
$c::getData(); // Output: Array('c'), Expected: Array('a', 'b', 'c');
$c::getData(); // Output: Array('d'), Expected: Array('a', 'b', 'd');
```

Is this possible at all?

**EDIT**: I have my data objects and each object has a set of rules for its properties. For example a User object has a property `name` which can be maximum 10 symbols, I define this in the user class' rules and then all user objects will obey the rule when their property `name` is about to be changed. The rules array is static because they apply to all objects of this class. However when I inherit it for example in a VIP user then the VIP will need to have additional rules for properties that the basic user doesn't have. I need to be able to extend the rules array but if I define such an array in the child class it just overwrites the parent rules which I also need.

Comment: Have you actually tried what you want to try?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes, but the results are only the elements the classes are declared with.

Comment: So please be more precise on *what is expected* and *what is the actual output*.

Comment: @D4V1D edited, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Is is possible? Yes. Is that indeed needed? I doubt. Please, explain the circumstances around your case.

Comment: @AlmaDo I added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes, there is a way to do it with only **parent class**  method:

```
class A
{
    public static $data = ['a'];

    public static function getData()
    {
        $result = static::$data;
        $class  = get_called_class();
        while ($class = get_parent_class($class)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, $class::$data);
        }

        return $result;  
    }
}

class B extends A 
{
    public static $data = ['b']; 
}

class C extends B 
{
    public static $data = ['c']; 
}

class D extends C 
{
    public static $data = ['d']; 
}
```

Demo [here](http://3v4l.org/32MrN).

If order matters, then change merge arguments order (right now it will be like it is in class hierarchy chain - from child to parent)

**Or, utilize [`class_parents()`](http://php.net/class_parents)**

```
class A
{
    public static $data = ['a'];

    public static function getData()
    {
        $classes  = [get_called_class()]; //no class with name "0"
        $classes += class_parents($classes[0]);
        return call_user_func_array('array_merge', 
            array_map(
                function($class) {
                    return $class::$data;
                }, 
                $classes
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Demo [here](http://3v4l.org/GH5LN). This is even shorter way. So it can be done with plain array mapping. Unfortunately, current class has to be added manually to the iterated hierarchy array.

Comment: I guess this is the cleanest solution of the ones suggested. The only thing troubling me is that this will run every time a property is changed, which means 10s of times per request. Maybe I could come up with a way to save the merged array into the child class the first time `getData()` is called.

Comment: `array_merge()` is slow by definition. By there's a trick around it: instead of doing merge in-place, gather your `$result` as elements and do `return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result)` - same result, only one merge.

Comment: @AlmaDo I've taken the liberty of simplifying your 2nd suggestion in terms of execution, removed 2 function calls and array declaration, as OP seems to be concerned about performance. Maybe narrowing it down to a simple loop would improve it even further but I'm not quite an internals guy so I can't definitely tell.

Answer (score 2):

This will achieve what you want

```
class A {
    static $data = ['a'];

    static function getData() { return self::$data; }
}

class B extends A {
    static $data = ['b'];

    static function getData() { return array_merge(parent::getData(), self::$data); }
}

class C extends B {
    static $data = ['c'];

    static function getData() { return array_merge(parent::getData(), self::$data); }
}

class D extends B {
    static $data = ['d'];

    static function getData() { return array_merge(parent::getData(), self::$data); }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$c = new C;
$d = new D;

var_dump($a::getData()); // Array('a');
var_dump($b::getData()); // Array('a', 'b');
var_dump($c::getData()); // Array('a', 'b', 'c');
var_dump($d::getData()); // Array('a', 'b', 'd');
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/ZX4me)

though there's probably a slightly cleaner way of doing it defining getData() only in class A

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I suppose I could use a trait for this but I'm still hoping there might be a simpler solution :c

Answer (score 2):

You want to merge the arrays, but in your example code you never specify this. The call to `get_parent_class(get_called_class())` gets the parent class, or false if it doesn't exist.

Also, you cannot use `self`, but you must use `static` if you want to use the value of the actual class that was called. `self` will always use the same value.

```
class A {
    static $data = ['a'];

    static function getData() {
        $parent = get_parent_class(get_called_class());
        if(method_exists($parent, 'getData')) {
            return array_merge($parent::getData(), static::$data);
        } else {
            return static::$data;
        }
    }
}
// other classes unchanged
```